# How to change value of setting for a custom configuration under play/sbt?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.2

I have a play project, and I want to add an sbt task that runs the application with a given folder available as a resource. However, I don't want that folder to be on the classpath during "normal" runs.

I created a configuration, added the resources to that configuration, but when I run in that configuration, the files aren't being picked up

for example, I have:

```
val Mock = config(“mock”) extend Compile
val mock = inputKey[Unit]("run in mock mode")

val project = Project(“my project”, file(“src/”))
.configs(Mock)
.settings(
      unmanagedResourceDirectories in Mock ++= Seq(baseDirectory.value / “mock-resources”)
      mock <<= run in Mock
)
```

I want it so that when I type `mock` the `mock-resources` is on the classpath, and when i type `run` it isn't.

I'm using play 2.2.0 with sbt 0.13.1

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the appropriate settings and tasks that are under `Compile` configuration to the newly-defined `Mock` configuration. The reason for this is this:

```
lazy val Mock = config("mock") extend Compile
```

When there's no setting or task under `Mock` sbt keeps searching in `Compile` where `run` is indeed defined but uses `Compile` values.

Do the following and it's going to work - note `Classpaths.configSettings` and `run` in `Seq`:

```
lazy val Mock = config("mock") extend Compile

lazy val mock = inputKey[Unit]("run in mock mode")

lazy val mockSettings = inConfig(Mock) {
  Classpaths.configSettings ++
  Seq(
    unmanagedClasspath += baseDirectory.value / "mock-resources",
    mock <<= run in Mock,
    run <<= Defaults.runTask(fullClasspath in Mock, mainClass in Mock, runner in Mock)
  )
}

lazy val p = (project in file("src/")).configs(Mock).settings(
  mockSettings: _*
)
```

**NOTE** I'm unsure why I needed the following line:

```
run <<= Defaults.runTask(fullClasspath in Mock, mainClass in Mock, runner in Mock)
```

My guess is that because `run` uses `fullClasspath` that defaults to `Compile` scope it doesn't see the value in `Mock`. *sbt keeps amazing me!*

I've asked about it in [Why does the default run task not pick settings in custom configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24981062/1305344)

### Sample

I've been running the build with the following `hello.scala` under `src` directory:

```
object Hello extends App {
    val r = getClass.getResource("/a.properties")
    println(s"resource: $r")
}
```

Upon `p/mock:mock` it gave me:

```
> p/mock:mock
[info] Running Hello
resource: file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/mock-config/src/mock-resources/a.properties
```

Same for `p/mock:run`:

```
> p/mock:run
[info] Running Hello
resource: file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/mock-config/src/mock-resources/a.properties
```

And `mock` was no different:

```
> mock
[info] Running Hello
resource: file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/mock-config/src/mock-resources/a.properties
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, unfortunately this doesn't work in the context of the Play! framework. Play overrides the run task, which I believe might be the cause of this whole predicament

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/PlayRun.scala#L92