# Why does the default run task not pick settings in custom configuration?

Tags: sbt

I use sbt `0.13.6-SNAPSHOT` built from the latest sources as of [commit 5b070b9dcc1dea25106573a86167517e5a8dc8d4](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/tree/5b070b9dcc1dea25106573a86167517e5a8dc8d4).

The issue came out when I was responding to [How to change value of setting for a custom configuration under play/sbt?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24933269/1305344).

This is **build.sbt**:

```
lazy val Mock = config("mock") extend Compile

lazy val mock = inputKey[Unit]("run in mock mode")

lazy val mockSettings = inConfig(Mock) {
  Classpaths.configSettings ++
  Seq(
    unmanagedClasspath += baseDirectory.value / "mock-resources",
    mock <<= run in Mock,
    run <<= Defaults.runTask(fullClasspath in Mock, mainClass in Mock, runner in Mock)
  )
}

lazy val p = (project in file("src/")).configs(Mock).settings(
  mockSettings: _*
)
```

Why is the custom `run` task needed for the custom `Mock` configuration? Why doesn't `run` pick `unmanagedClasspath` for the `Mock` configuration?

See the following session:

```
> mock
[info] Running Hello
resource: file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/mock-config/src/mock-resources/a.properties
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jul 27, 2014 2:26:07 PM
> p/mock:run
[info] Running Hello
resource: file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/mock-config/src/mock-resources/a.properties
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jul 27, 2014 2:26:34 PM
> p/mock:mock
[info] Running Hello
resource: file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/mock-config/src/mock-resources/a.properties
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jul 27, 2014 2:27:01 PM
```

It works fine.

The following line gets removed from `build.sbt`:

```
run <<= Defaults.runTask(fullClasspath in Mock, mainClass in Mock, runner in Mock)
```

This is the only change for the build definition. No other files are touched.

```
> reload
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Set current project to mock-config (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/mock-config/)
> p/mock:mock
[info] Running Hello
resource: null
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jul 27, 2014 2:28:31 PM
> p/mock:run
[info] Running Hello
resource: null
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jul 27, 2014 2:28:36 PM
> mock
[info] Running Hello
resource: null
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jul 27, 2014 2:28:39 PM
```

Why does the default `run` task not work for the custom `Mock` configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Please use a released version to ask questions such as 0.13.5.

If you run `inspect` command, it should be clear that you have not defined `run` task when you remove `run <<= ....` from `build.sbt`:

```
p> inspect mock:run
[info] Input task: Unit
[info] Description:
[info]  Runs a main class, passing along arguments provided on the command line.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file:/Users/foo/sbt-so-24981062/}p/compile:run
[info] Defined at:
[info]  (sbt.Defaults) Defaults.scala:731
```

This is because `Classpaths.configSettings` doesn't include `run` task.

Comment: It doesn't work for `Defaults.configSettings`, either so when I change  `Classpaths.configSettings` to `Defaults.configSettings` that does include `run` task it gets worse :( Why?